# Permutation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, permutation

**Here is my problem:**

For a given sentence, find occurrences of the given character set. Pick filtered words and generate permutations. (SENTENCE AND CHARACTER SET ONLY CAN HAVE UPPERCASE LETTERS)

Show selected words & permutations

**Example:**

*Inputs*

```
sentence = "THIS IS AN ISSUE FROM JOHN" 
word = "IS"
```

*Output:*

```
{ 
  words: ["THIS", "IS", "ISSUE"], 
  permutations: [["THIS","IS","ISSUE"], ["IS","THIS","ISSUE"], ["ISSUE","THIS","IS"], ["THIS","ISSUE","IS"], ["IS","ISSUE","THIS"], ["ISSUE","IS","THIS"]] 
}
```

And the following criteria should be fulfilled:

1. Return type should be an object.
2. `getPermutations("THIS IS AN ISSUE FROM GIHAN", "IS")`

   Should return:

   ```
   { 
     "word": ["THIS","IS","ISSUE"], 
     "permutations": [["THIS","IS","ISSUE"], ["IS","THIS","ISSUE"], ["ISSUE", "THIS", "IS"], ["THIS", "ISSUE", "IS"], ["IS", "ISSUE", "THIS"], ["ISSUE","IS","THIS"]]
   }
   ```
3. Answer should be valid for any given input.

*Here is my code:*

```
function getPermutations(sentence, word) {
  var words = sentence.split(" ");
  var x = words[0] +" "+ words[1] +" "+ words[3];
  var inputArray = x.split(" ");
  var permutations = inputArray.reduce(function permute(res, item, key, arr) {
    return res.concat(arr.length > 1 && arr.slice(0, key).concat(arr.slice(key + 1)).reduce(permute, []).map(function(perm) { return [item].concat(perm); }) || item);

}, []);

  var output = { words: words,permutations :  permutations}; 


  return output;
}

console.log(getPermutations("THIS IS AN ISSUE FROM JOHN", "IS"));
```

there is some error so it confusing with this. Any suggestion please?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this code: `var x = words[0] +" "+ words[1] +" "+ words[3];`? You seem to be not filtering the words in the sentence by the given `word`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regex (`/\w*IS\w*/g`) and [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to extract the words containing the characters you specify. Use a Set to remove the duplicates, then generate the permutations of that array with [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat), [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
function permutations(arr) {
  return (arr.length === 1) ? arr : arr.reduce((acc, x, i) => {
    const remaining = [...new Set(arr)].filter((y, j) => i !== j);
    return [...acc, ...permutations(remaining).map(a => [x, a].flat())];
  }, []);
}

function getPermutations(str, word) {
  const words = [...new Set(
    (word && (str || '').match(new RegExp(`\\w*${word}\\w*`, 'g'))) || [])
  ];
  return { words, permutations: permutations(words) };
}

console.log(getPermutations('THIS IS AN ISSUE FROM JOHN', 'IS'));
console.log(getPermutations('THIS IS', 'IS'));
console.log(getPermutations('', 'IS'));
console.log(getPermutations(null, 'IS'));
console.log(getPermutations('', ''));
console.log(getPermutations('', null));
```

Comment: This one is correct but not fulfil the 3rd requirement. Thanks.

Comment: @jhone, where is it failing regarding your 3rd requirement ?

Comment: 3. Answer should be valid for any given input.

Comment: @jhone, what do you define as valid ? I return empty arrays when no result is found, and I even added lots of examples to show the method robustness, do you have a value I can test with?

Comment: oh no i only check with first value. i will check with others. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could split the words at every space and [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) only those which have the specified `word` in them. Then get every permutation from the array of words

```js
function getPermutations(sentence, word) {
  const matches = sentence.split(" ").filter(w => w.includes(word));
  
  let permutations = permute(matches);
  
  return {
    word: matches,
    permutations
  }
}

/*
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/37580979/3082296
*/
function permute(permutation) {
  var length = permutation.length,
    result = [permutation.slice()],
    c = new Array(length).fill(0),
    i = 1,
    k, p;

  while (i < length) {
    if (c[i] < i) {
      k = i % 2 && c[i];
      p = permutation[i];
      permutation[i] = permutation[k];
      permutation[k] = p;
      ++c[i];
      i = 1;
      result.push(permutation.slice());
    } else {
      c[i] = 0;
      ++i;
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(getPermutations("THIS IS AN ISSUE FROM GIHAN", "IS"))
```

Note: If you have the words separated by punctuation marks like comma (,) or period (.), then use word boundaries in regex:

```
const matches = sentence.match(/\b(\w+)\b/g)
```

**Reference**: Permutation of array items code is taken [**from this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37580979/3082296)

Comment: thanks.. almost is ok.. but there is some error called: cannot read property 'sort' of undefined

Comment: yes.. but it show "Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined. i don't know where is the error coming from.
"

Answer (score 1):

```js
  function getPermutations(sentence,word) {        
        var pieces = sentence.split(" ");
        var valid_pcs = [];
        var combinations = [[]];
        var combinations_no_duplicates = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < pieces.length; i++) {
            if (pieces[i].indexOf(word) !== -1)
                valid_pcs.push(pieces[i]);
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < valid_pcs.length; i++) {
            tmp = [];
            for (var j = 0; j < combinations.length; j++) {
                for (var k = 0; k < valid_pcs.length; k++)
                    tmp.push(combinations[j].concat(valid_pcs[k]));
            }
            combinations = tmp;
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < combinations.length; i++) {
            const distinct = [...new Set(combinations[i])];
            if (distinct.length == combinations[i].length)
                combinations_no_duplicates.push(combinations[i]);
        }
        return {"word":valid_pcs,"permutations":combinations_no_duplicates};
    }
    
    console.log(getPermutations("THIS IS AN ISSUE FROM JOHN", "IS"));
```